# wifi auto reconnection

Tags: shell-script, wifi

usually wifi reconnects after dropping,but sometimes it will show the wifi log in screen already filled in,waiting to press on connect after that a new connection will form with #2 after the duplicate ssid.

sometimes i just untick/tick the 'enable networking'.other times,it wont reconnect.

i tried to form a script,but it continues to accumulate & count even when there is no badpings before reaching the max limit of 30 counts.

```
while true; 
do
    if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
        echo "no ping,will reset" 

    #counter of bad pings here
    count=1             
    while [ $count -lt 30 ]
        do
            count=`expr $count + 1`
            echo "$count"
            # insert here: retest for good ping
            sleep 1
        done


        nmcli networking off 
        sleep 5 
        nmcli networking on


        #sleep for 15sec wait wifi on ssid search        
        secs=$((1 * 15))
        while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do
        echo -ne "$secs\033[0K\r"wifi reactivate in- 
        sleep 1
         : $((secs--))
        done


        if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
             echo "still offline for $count x @ $(date)" 

         else 
         count=0
             #echo "reconnected at $(date)" 
         echo "ON"
        fi
        else

        echo "ONLINE"
        sleep 1
    clear
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then` line is flawed.  What are you trying to accomplish there?  This is always going to error and therefore be true since you are negating it.

Comment: Your `while [ $count -lt 30 ]` does nothing except count to 30 and print the counter each time. What are you expecting it to do differently? Are you having trouble figuring out how to exit the `while` loop? Or are you asking how to test if the ping works?

Comment: @KevinKruse & Jesse_b  I want to exit the count to 30 if there is a sudden good ping.

Comment: objective: 1. the script will stay running in the background to check for wifi disconnection 2.It should count a max of  30 badpings (because sometimes its just having slow response time ) then it will reset wifi.. if there is a sudden good ping before reaching the 30max,reseting should halt and counter will go back to zero.

Comment: What OS? Do you know why your signal is disconnecting? Your approach seems hackish

Comment: ubuntu xenial. might be from the rainy weather

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you want but can definitely be improved further:

```
while :; do
    if ! ping -c1 google.com >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "no ping,will reset" 
        #counter of bad pings here
        count=1             
        while [ "$count" -lt 30 ]; do
            echo "$count"
            # insert here: retest for good ping
            nmcli networking off 
            sleep 5 
            nmcli networking on
            if ! ping -c1 google.com >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo "still offline for $count x @ $(date)" 
            else 
                #echo "reconnected at $(date)" 
                echo "ON"
                break
            fi
            ((count++))
            sleep 1
        done
    else
        echo "ONLINE"
        sleep 1
        clear
    fi
done
```